# JPA Entity - Sql hierarchyid type mapping

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.1

I've a table on db with a field of type hierarchyid as ID.
How to map this field on an @Entity using Java/JPA (hibernate)?

Thanks
Mirko

Answer (score 0):

you can try with eclipse, in the project, click new / others / JPA Entity from tables and see how to generate automatically thsi field